# Help working out the believability of some evidence

Tags: belief, evidence, conspiracies

Suppose I have some evidence of where I was while a crime was being committed, a recording of me visiting a bank and asking for the time of a transaction (which was completed at that time elsewhere). I was being accused of committing this crime, so someone phoned the bank and asked if the transaction existed, and they were told no. Allow me that there was - before the phone-call - originally a 95% chance of the recording being real and not a deep fake (there is no evidence I have the capacity to deep fake), and only a 90% chance that no-one would/did change the transaction time (my enemies are nerds). Does that mean my evidence is more reliable? If my innocence is trivially derived from the authenticity of the recording, then am I more likely to be innocent, whatever other evidence there was before the phone-call?

Comment: while "deep fakes" may be fairly easy to make, i don't think you can just dismiss recordings etc. as fake, not with more than 5% certainty. not for someone you have no evidence ever took an interest in these things. the mistake my accusers are making is that they are **fixing** the chance of a nerd conspiracy and not the chance of me faking recordings etc..

Comment: Your question is so badly worded that it is impossible to answer. You speak of "whatever other evidence there was" without specifying how it bears on your innocence, you don't specify whether your enemies know whether your transaction is fake and whether they would modify it only so as to make you look guilty if you are not, you don't specify from an impartial observer's point of view the prior probability that you are guilty. The most you could calculate is a likelihood ratio, but even that would require additional assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

So before the call there's a 95% chance the recording is real and a 5% chance the recording is fake. You said there's a "90% chance that no-one would/did change the transaction time." Let's imagine that this 90% chance is the same regardless of whether the recording is real.

That means, *before* the phone call, there's (A) a .90*.95 chance the recording is real and no one changed the transaction. There's (B) a .10*.95 chance the recording is real and someone did change the transaction. There's (C) a .90*.05 chance the recording is fake and no one changed the transaction. And there's (D) a .10 * .05 chance the recording is fake and someone did change the transaction.

After the phone call, (A) is ruled out because the recording and the transaction contradict each other. (B) is possible (meaning you're innocent), (C) is possible (meaning you're guilty), and (D) is at least very unlikely, because you wouldn't have a need to fake the recording if the transaction actually happened. Let's assume (D) is ruled out for practical purposes too.

So the probability you're innocent is P(B) / (P(A) + P(B)) = .10*.95 / (.10*.95 + .90*.05) = 68%.

Comment: confusing, but thanks (I am indeed innocent haha)

Answer (score 0):

E = The evidence (the recording of a bank transaction) is true
C = The phone call contradicting your evidence

P(E/C) = The probability of your evidence being true given that the phone call contradicts your evidence
P(C/E) = The probability of the phone call contradicting your evidence given the evidence is true
P(E) = The probability that the evidence is true
P(C) = The probability that the phone call contradicts your evidence

**Bayes' Theorem**
We have to calculate the following:
P(E/C) = [P(C/E)*P(E)]/P(C)

P(E) = 95%, P(C) = 10%, P(C/E) = very, very low, say 5% (this we have to estimate)

P(E/C) = (5% * 95%)/10% = 47.5%

### The *believability* (the probability it is true) of your evidence fell from 95% to 47.5%.

Another way ta look at this problem would be to calculate the probability of the evidence being false.

P(F) = the probability of the evidence being false (believability)
P(C) = the probability the call will contradict the evidence
P(F/C) = the probability that the evidence is false given that the call will contradict the evidence
P(C/F) = the probability that the call will contradict the evidence given that the evidence is false.

P(F) = 5%, P(C) = 10%, P(C/F) = 90%

P(F/C) = [P(C/F) × P(F)]/P(C) = (90% × 5%)/10% = 45%

The likelihood that the evidence is false (unbelievability) rose from 5% to 45%

Comment: how can that be less than 50% when it is much more believable than the counter evidence? why isn't the P(C/E) = 0?

Comment: -1 cos you've randomly added another variable. either my evidence is real or the phonecall is. they can't both be authentic, that's the point

Comment: @doot_s  P(C/E) *isn't* 0 because the evidence is, per your setup, only 95% true.  Think of it this way: Either your evidence is true or not true. If the probability that it is true is high (you assigned a 95% probability) then the probability of the phone call contradicting your evidence will be low.

Comment: i can't see what mistake you've made, but no way are you right

Comment: the probability of the evidence being true is 95%. what do you mean "The probability of the phone call contradicting your evidence given the evidence is true"? it is zero.

Comment: @doot_s, *tampering with evidence*? Evidence is true but the call contradicts the evidence???

Comment: The chance of both being true is zero. I can't have bought these items and not bought these items. "Evidence is true but the call contradicts the evidence" do you mean the chance the call isn't authentic. That is 10%

Comment: @doot_s, all I mean is there's no *logical necessity* that the call *verify* your evidence (you did say there's a 10% chance that the evidence can be compromised). This 10% probability *doesn't* factor in the evidence that you submit. Once you offer the evidence, the probability of the call contradicting your evidence *given* this new piece of information has to be *different*, lower, no?

Comment: no i don't understand, and i think you are misusing bayes theorem, which is not for mutually exclusive beliefs

Comment: @doot_s, your scenario includes the evidence being true *and* the call negating the evidence. Thye're *not* mutually exclusive events. To my reckoning, they would be mutually exclusive IFF the evidence is 100% true XOR the phone call is 100% correct as regards the falsity of your evidence. Both are false.

Comment: they can't both accurately represent what transactions occurred when, which is the key questuion.

Comment: so what's wrong with my answer? we have completely different values

Comment: i think i get this now. maybe

Answer (score 0):

I have evidence (signed letters form the bank, recorded phone-calls to customer services) I completed some transaction at some time. We agree that its authenticity was 95% believable.

Someone else tried to call the bank, and they said no such transaction existed.

We agree - for the sake of argument - the authenticity of that is less believable than my documents etc..

If 90% without my evidence, then mine is twice as believable. Based on these probabilities the chances the transaction occurred at that time is 2:1 or 2/3rd or 67%

---

### Alternatively, you may want to use 95% as A Bayesian "prior probability" of no deep fakes, in order to update it

But you need two probabilities - that of a conspiracy against authentic recordings, as well as the probability of a conspiracy, to use BT (if these are both 0.1 then the posteriori probability is the prior, 95%).

Suppose we take 0.1 as the probability of someone tampering with my bank details, and use the marginal probability of the chance of a conspiracy in general. For a posterior probability of 0.6 - a fairly robust belief in my recordings - we need a marginal probability of 0.15.

Suppose we take 0.1 as the marginal probability, then we need the chance of interference to be 0.158, to believe my evidence at 0.6.

If we take the marginal probability to be the inverse of the probability of my authenticity, then the updated odds of my authenticity is 0.48.  **Enough to assume 'innocence' anyway!**

But without those, this is pseudo statistics.

Answer (score 0):

> Allow me that there was - before the phone-call - originally a 95%
> chance of the recording being real and not a deep fake (there is no
> evidence I have the capacity to deep fake), and only a 90% chance that
> no-one would/did change the transaction time (my enemies are nerds).

Presumably they would change the transaction time only if the recording was real. So you're talking about the *plausibility* of events, not updating prior probabilities.

It's 2/3.

---

What do we call someone who knows they keep making the same mistakes, despite seeming intelligent?